# How to make my menu Responsive for Bootstrap Navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Ok so I am trying make my 3d menu responsive to fit to the bootstrap nav menu. Right now it is not responsive so when I see it on my mobile device it overlays the bootstrap navigational bar. What I want is some type of CSS or html to make each button on the menu responsive to shrink to the size of the nav bar once its viewed on a smaller device.

JS fiddle LInk https://jsfiddle.net/ap3x6swe/

Heres My CSS

```
    .block-menu {
        display: block;
        background: transparent; 
    }

    .block-menu li {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .block-menu li a {
        color: #666;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif !important;
        font-smoothing: antialiased;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        overflow: visible;
        line-height: 18px;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 15px 10px;
    }

    /* animation domination */
    .three-d {
        perspective: 200px;
        transition: all .07s linear;
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
        /* complete the animation! */
        .three-d:hover .three-d-box, 
        .three-d:focus .three-d-box {
            transform: translateZ(-25px) rotateX(90deg);
        }

    .three-d-box {
        transition: all .3s ease-out;
        transform: translatez(-25px);
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        pointer-events: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    /* 
        put the "front" and "back" elements into place with CSS transforms, 
        specifically translation and translatez
    */
    .front {
        transform: rotatex(0deg) translatez(25px);
    }

    .back {
        transform: rotatex(-90deg) translatez(25px);
        color: #ffe7c4;
    }

    .front, .back {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: DarkGrey;
        padding: 17px 10px;
        color: white;
        pointer-events: none;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

Heres HTML

```
<ul class="block-menu" id="navmenu">
    <li><a href="/" class="three-d menu_nav" >
        Home
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box img-responsive">
            <span class="front">Home</span>
            <span class="back">Home</span>
        </span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="pages/home.html" class="three-d menu_nav img-responsive">
        Artist
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
            <span class="front">Roster</span>
            <span class="back">Roster</span>
        </span>
    </a></li>

    <li><a href="pages/order.html" class="three-d menu_nav">
        Labels
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
            <span class="front">Labels</span>
            <span class="back">Labels</span>
        </span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="/" class="three-d menu_nav">
        Music
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
            <span class="front">Music</span>
            <span class="back">Music</span>
        </span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="/" class="three-d menu_nav">
        Videos
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
            <span class="front">Videos</span>
            <span class="back">Videos</span>
        </span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="/" class="three-d menu_nav">
        Store
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
            <span class="front">Store</span>
            <span class="back">Store</span>
        </span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="/" class="three-d menu_nav">
        Services
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
            <span class="front">Services</span>
            <span class="back">Services</span>
        </span>
    </a></li>
     <li><a href="/" class="three-d menu_nav">
        Artist Resources
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
            <span class="front">Artist Resources</span>
            <span class="back">Artist Resources</span>
        </span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="/" class="three-d menu_nav">
        Contact Us
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
            <span class="front">Contact Us</span>
            <span class="back">Contact Us</span>
        </span>
    </a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Please add js fiddle link also

Comment: @kumar heres the js fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/ap3x6swe/

Comment: add script with  bootstrap navigational bar

Comment: @Trillu http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar please follow this example for bootstrap responsive navigation. Neither we need to make custom responsive using media queries

and please don't forget import all bootstrap library like css, js

Comment: Please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ap3x6swe/3/
and i have post to answer also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this fiddle. I have added bootstrap all external library and change little bit structure. `[https://jsfiddle.net/ap3x6swe/3/][1]`

Comment: I figured It out using your @media script at the bottom of the css... I Didnt want the navigational bar to collapse.... thats why I needed it to be responsive